# Cancel Amazon S3 Put object Request

Tags: android, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload files to Amazon S3, nothing special. I have managed to do the actual upload, and the file uploads successfully. The only issue that's left is that how to cancel or abort putobject request

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue and ended up using `FileInputStream` instead of `File` for the `PutRequest` and force close the stream to cancel the upload.

This cancels the put request because it cannot try again because it lacks the reference to the file.

```
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
metadata.setContentLength(file.length());
PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest(bucket, key, inputStream, metadata);
```

To cancel upload

```
inputStream.close();
```

Unfortunately this fills up logcat with `ClientProtocolException` stack traces.

Comment: but it give IOException Attempted to close inputStream.

Comment: That's expected since you're forcefully closing the stream so catch the exception and ignore it. You could set a boolean flag to distinguish it from other exceptions.

Comment: can you provide any example because when i forcefully close inputstream it will hangup for a while.

Comment: If there is a pause, I've never noticed it because I have always been using it in a background thread. As far as I know, there is no API method to cancel a PutRequest and this is the only way I found.

Answer (score 0):

To Cancel the upload, please have a look on this, I am doing same and it is working fine.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String clientRegion = "*** Client region ***";
    String bucketName = "*** Bucket name ***";
    String keyName = "*** Object key ***";
    String filePath = "*** Path to file to upload ***";

    try {
        AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                .withRegion(clientRegion)
                .withCredentials(new ProfileCredentialsProvider())
                .build();
        TransferManager tm = TransferManagerBuilder.standard()
                            .withS3Client(s3Client)
                            .build();
        PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, keyName, new File(filePath));

        // To receive notifications when bytes are transferred, add a  
        // ProgressListener to your request.
        request.setGeneralProgressListener(new ProgressListener() {
            public void progressChanged(ProgressEvent progressEvent) {
                System.out.println("Transferred bytes: " + progressEvent.getBytesTransferred());
                }
        });
        // TransferManager processes all transfers asynchronously,
        // so this call returns immediately.
        Upload upload = tm.upload(request);

        // Optionally, you can wait for the upload to finish before continuing.
        upload.waitForCompletion();
    }
    catch(AmazonServiceException e) {
        // The call was transmitted successfully, but Amazon S3 couldn't process 
        // it, so it returned an error response.
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(SdkClientException e) {
        // Amazon S3 couldn't be contacted for a response, or the client 
        // couldn't parse the response from Amazon S3.
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HLTrackProgressMPUJava.html

for cancel the upload use below code on background thread

```
transferManager.shutdownNow();
```